# CSS: First row of image gallery coming out diagonal?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have an array of images in php that I am trying to display as a gallery. It is working pretty well, except that the first row of the gallery comes out diagonal, with each image slightly below the one before it.

Here is the code I am using:

**CSS**

```
.gallery {
      margin: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      float: left;
      display: inline;
      width:180px;
      height:180px;
    }

    .gallery:hover {
        border: 1px solid #777;
    }

    .gallery img {
        max-height:100%;
        max-width:100%;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
```

**HTML/PHP**

```
<div class="gallery-container">
<?php
    $count = 0;
    foreach($images as $image) {
        echo "<div class='gallery'><a href=''><img src='".$dir.$image."'/></a></div>"; //$dir is the path to the image
        if(count % 4 == 0) {
            echo "<br>";
        }
        $count = $count + 1;
    }
?>
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot of the result on the first row:
[image]

All the other rows come out fine. Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: use firebug or another tool to see what HTML element is causing the additional space - i expect it is the <br> in the echo.

Comment: now only the first picture is slightly raised. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: The line break is now after the first image.

Comment: wow awesome. thank you so much

Comment: Also: using `float: left` will make elements block-level anyway, so the `display: inline` property will be ignored.

Comment: @Jared If you tried my answer, please let me know if it helped you resolve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it using `float`, you would better do that like this:

**CSS**

```
.gallery{
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width:180px;
  height:180px;
}
.gallery.clear-left{
  clear: left;
}
```

**PHP/HTML**

```
<div class="gallery-container">
<?php
    $count = 0;
    foreach( $images as $image ){?>
        <div class="gallery <?php echo( 0 == $count % 4 ? 'clear-left' : '' );?>">
            <a href="">
                <img src="<?php echo $dir.$image;?>">
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php
        $count++;
    }
?>
</div>
```

But there is an even better solution to this, called **[flex](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties)**:

Comment: this worked thanks. didn't really understand how to use flex tho.

Comment: Here you may see [a good example of Flex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35247417/put-footer-content-in-columns/35247427#35247427)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **br** element render "clear" div

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the resulting html. It is likely that you count is off and the br is being put to the dom too often. This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jeremythuff/bqx0qosh/) shows that your desired html and css should work.

```
<div class='gallery'><a href=''><img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/Hausziege_04.jpg'/></a></div>
<div class='gallery'><a href=''><img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/Hausziege_04.jpg'/></a></div>
<div class='gallery'><a href=''><img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/Hausziege_04.jpg'/></a></div>
<div class='gallery'><a href=''><img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/Hausziege_04.jpg'/></a></div>
<br>
```

Though, I would consider not using the br, but instead using a containing div:

like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jeremythuff/Lc1fg541/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried starting the count at 1 instead of 0?

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.